# Testing Ajax call with a JSON response returns unexpected token

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a Vue app with the following code...

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#Workbooks',
components: {
    'workbook-list': workbooklist
},
data: {
    workbooks: [],
    message: '',
    loading: true,
    error: false
},
mounted: function () {
    this.getWorkbooks();
},
methods: {
    getWorkbooks: function () {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/LandingPage/getWorkbooks',
            success: function (response) {
                var results = JSON.parse(response);
                that.workbooks = results.workbooks.workbook;
                that.checkResults();
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
                that.loading = false;
                that.message = 'Sorry, there was a problem fetching your reports. Please try later.';
                that.error = true,
                console.log(xhr.status + ' ' + exception);
            },

        });
    },
     checkResults: function() {
        this.workbooks.length ? this.loading = false : this.message = 'You currently do not have any reports set up.';
    }
},
```

});

All is working fine but I want to test that on a successful AJAX call it's doing what it should.

I have the following Jasmine code that I am running via Karma...

```
it('should check the results on Ajax success', function () {
    spyOn(vm, "checkResults");
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (e) {
        e.success({}); 
    });

    vm.getWorkbooks();

    expect("checkResults").toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I have two issues. One is that I'm getting a 404 error in the logs on the AJAX URL (it points to an ASP.NET MVC controller, not a physical file). The second is the test fails with '**SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**'. I'm assuming this is because it's now just returning an object and it's trying to parse JSON that doesn't exist? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is how can I resolve this and what is the correct way to unit test these sort of AJAX calls as I'm obviously missing something? Essentially I just want to somehow mock out that response.

I don't know if it's worth noting as well that I am using these tools standalone, so I'm not using anything like Webpack to bundle things together and run them.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need `;` not `,` in below code

```
that.loading = false;
that.message = 'Sorry, there was a problem fetching your reports. Please try later.';
that.error = true; // on this line need ';' not ','
console.log(xhr.status + ' ' + exception);
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah that was just a typo I somehow managed when I copied the code over. It's not like that in source.